# ASP.NET MVC C# - No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm having a problem in my code. Can someone  help me.

1. When running the line "comm.ExecuteScalar();", I received an error message.
2. Error Message says "No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type."
3. My stored proc is attached.

Code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Convert.ToString(database.DbConnect("database1"))))
{
    var procedure = "sp_auth_sign_in";
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(procedure, conn))
        {
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", model.EmployeeId);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", model.Password);
            comm.Parameters.Add("@emp_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@role_group", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@chg_pass", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@img_path", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@division_group", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@department_group", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@logintries", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@uname_docutrack", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@ustatus_docutrack", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@SignatoryInitial", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.ExecuteScalar(); // got an error here.
```

Code for sp_auth_sign_in procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_auth_sign_in]
@employeeid       varchar(25)='', /* username for contractors; employee id for */
@password         varchar(25)='',
@emp_name         varchar(50)  output,
@role_group       varchar(2)   output,
@chg_pass         bit          output,
@img_path         varchar(100) output,
@division_group   varchar(3)   output,
@department_group varchar(3)   output,
@firstname        varchar(25)  output,
@logintries       int          output,
@uname_docutrack  varchar(50)  output,
@ustatus_docutrack  bit  output,
@SignatoryInitial   varchar(3) output,
@result           int output
as

/*****************************

  Date  : June 17, 2015
 *****************************/

/* variable(s) */
declare 
@statvar    bit=0,
@stat_tries tinyint=0,
@passcode   int=0

set @logintries = 0

/* trim white space(s) */
set @employeeid=dbo.fn_lrtrim(@employeeid)
set @password=dbo.fn_lrtrim(@password)

/* raise error for null entries or any */
if(@employeeid='')
begin
    set @result=1
    return 1
end

if(@password='')
begin
    set @result=2
    return 2
end

/* check if username/employee id is valid.  */
if not exists
(
    select
        aum.employeeid
    from dbo.app_users_megaworld aum with (nolock)
    where aum.employeeid=@employeeid
)
begin
    set @result=3
    return 3
end

/* check if account is active */
select
    @statvar=aur.active
from dbo.app_users_roles aur with (nolock)
where aur.employeeid=@employeeid
if(@statvar=0)
begin
    set @result=4
    return 4
end

/* count login attempts */
select
    @stat_tries=aur.tries
from dbo.app_users_roles aur with (nolock)
where aur.employeeid=@employeeid
if(@stat_tries>=5)
begin
    /* deactivate account if tries>=3 */
    exec dbo.sp_app_users_active @employeeid, 0

    /* reset login attempt in effect for the account deactivation */
    exec dbo.sp_app_users_tries @employeeid, 0

    set @result=5
    return 5
end

/* check username and password combination */
exec dbo.sp_crt_user_passcode @employeeid, @password, @passcode output
if not exists
(
    select
        aur.passcode
    from dbo.app_users_roles aur with (nolock)
    where aur.employeeid=@employeeid and aur.passcode=@passcode
)
begin
    /* increase counter for login attempt(s) */
    exec dbo.sp_app_users_tries @employeeid, 1

    select @logintries = tries from app_users_roles where employeeid = @employeeid

    set @result=6
    return 6
end



/* account is valid */
/* reset counter for login attempt(s) */
exec dbo.sp_app_users_tries @employeeid, 0

/* raise flag for signing-in */
exec dbo.sp_app_users_logon @employeeid, 1 -- <-- change to 1 in production

/* output user's information */
select
    --@emp_name=rtrim(upper(aum.firstname) + ' ' + upper(aum.lastname) + ' ' + upper(iif(aum.suffix='', '', aum.suffix))) ,
    @emp_name=rtrim(aum.firstname + ' ' + aum.lastname + ' ' + iif(aum.suffix='', '', aum.suffix)) ,
    @role_group=aur.role_group,
    @chg_pass=aur.chg_pass,
    @img_path=iif(aum.img_path is null or aum.img_path='','/Images/Avatar/avatar.jpg', aum.img_path),
    @division_group=aum.division_group,
    @department_group=aum.department_group,
    @firstname=upper(aum.firstname),
    @uname_docutrack = isnull(aud.username,''),
    @ustatus_docutrack = isnull(aud.accountstatus,0),
    @SignatoryInitial = isnull(aum.SignatureInitial, '')
from dbo.app_users_megaworld aum with (nolock)
inner join dbo.app_users_roles aur with (nolock)
    on aum.employeeid=aur.employeeid
full join dbo.app_user_roles_docutrack aud
    on aum.employeeid = aud.employeeid and aud.systemtype = 'MyTracking'
where aum.employeeid=@employeeid



set @result=0
return 0
GO
```

---

Update:

The problem is here:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", model.EmployeeId);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", model.Password);
```

-In my storedproc, the datatype of employeeId is varchar but in my Model view it is set as "dynamic".

-I really don't know what's happening here since i'm just a newbie but when I changed it to "string", it works well.

-Remaining issue is when I'm setting a session.

Error here:

```
Session["EmployeeID"] = model.EmployeeId.Replace(",", "").ToUpper;

Error   2   Cannot convert method group 'ToUpper' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?




namespace WMSPortal.Models
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {

        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
       //public dynamic EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

Comment: `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();` ?

Comment: Test 1: var count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());

Test 2: string getValue = Convert.ToString(comm.ExecuteScalar());

Test 3: object o = comm.ExecuteScalar();

Test 4: comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Tried above solutions but still getting same error.

Comment: Please include the source code of `sp_auth_sign_in`.

Comment: Which field being passed in a `string[]`?

Comment: @mjwills please see attached.

JoeWilson the fields being passed in a string[] are the below, basically i'm getting the data in my Model.

.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", model.EmployeeId)

.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", model.Password)

Comment: Can you try Session["EmployeeID"] = model.EmployeeId.Replace(",", "").ToUpper();